# Copy paste row to multiple Sheets if cell matches not efficient

Tags: excel, vba, coding-efficiency

Here's the problem: The data is on one sheet and I need to classify it. The way I am trying to go at it is the following:

I wanted to first use this code to copy and paste into the appropriate sheet, but the only thig it's doing is pasting everything into TargetK and TargetL

```
Sub Button6_Click()


Dim c As Range
Dim j As Long
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim TargetA As Worksheet
Dim TargetB As Worksheet
Dim TargetC As Worksheet
Dim TargetD As Worksheet
Dim TargetE As Worksheet
Dim TargetF As Worksheet
Dim TargetG As Worksheet
Dim TargetH As Worksheet
Dim TargetI As Worksheet
Dim TargetJ As Worksheet
Dim TargetK As Worksheet
Dim TargetL As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") 'Where it is copying from
Set TargetA = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1Dyn") 'Where it is copying to
Set TargetB = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table2Dyn")
Set TargetC = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1Elec")
Set TargetD = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table2Elec")
Set TargetE = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1Hab")
Set TargetF = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table2Hab")
Set TargetG = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1HVAC")
Set TargetH = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table2HVAC")
Set TargetI = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1ITS")
Set TargetJ = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table2ITS")
Set TargetK = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1MISC")
Set TargetL = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table2MISC")


j = 3
For Each c In Source.Range("K3:K3000")
    If c = "03 - Dynamique" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetA.Rows(j)
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetB.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
       Else

         If c = "*04 - Electrique*" Then
         Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetC.Rows(j)
         Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetD.Rows(j)
         j = j + 1
         Else

             If c = "*06 - Habillage*" Then
             Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetE.Rows(j)
             Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetF.Rows(j)
             j = j + 1
             Else

                 If c = "*07 - HVAC*" Then
                 Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetG.Rows(j)
                 Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetH.Rows(j)
                 j = j + 1
                 Else

                    If c = "*08 - ITS*" Then
                     Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetI.Rows(j)
                     Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetJ.Rows(j)
                     j = j + 1
                     Else

             Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetK.Rows(j)
             Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy TargetL.Rows(j)
             j = j + 1

                     End If
                 End If
             End If
        End If
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

After that, I wanted to go into each sheet and delete the rows and columns that don't belong there.
There has to be a more efficient way to do this but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Use a `Select Case` here. Are  you trying to use the `*` as wildcards? That doesn't work with an `=` comparison.

Comment: ^^ Did you meant to use the `Like` operator? Otherwise these strings need to match exact. Which, is my guess, they don't resulting in copying all into `TargetK` and `TargetL`

Comment: I tried both, if you notice for 'TargetA' and 'TargetB', it still didn't work

Comment: If you want to use wildcards you need to use **Like** not `=`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
Sub Button6_Click()

    Dim v, ws, e, wb As Workbook, cNext As Range, j As Long, c As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    j = 3
    For Each c In wb.Worksheets("Data").Range("K3:K3000")

        v = c.Value
        ws = Empty

        'where are we copying to ?
        Select Case True
            Case v Like "*03 - Dynamique*": ws = Array("Table1Dyn", "Table2Dyn")
            Case v Like "*04 - Electrique*": ws = Array("Table1Elec", "Table2Elec")
            'add your other cases here
        End Select

        'found a match?
        If Not IsEmpty(ws) Then
            'copy to destination sheet(s)
            For Each e In ws
                c.EntireRow.Copy wb.Worksheets(e).Cells(j, j)

                'or do you want each sheet to fill row by row?
                'Set cNext = wb.Worksheets(e).Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                'c.EntireRow.Copy cNext.EntireRow.Cells(1)
            Next e
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```